# Artillery load testing tool, create additional socket per simulated user

Tags: performance, socket.io

I want to perform a load test with Artillert on my socket.io server run on localhost:8081.

Here is the socket.io part:

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {

  console.log("new socket connected: " + socket.id);

  socket.on("message", function (data) {

    console.log("socket " + socket.id + " send message");

  });

  socket.on("disconnect", function (data) {

    console.log("disconnect: " + socket.id)

  })

});
```

The script:

```
config:
  target: "http://localhost:8081"
  phases:
    - duration: 1
    arrivalRate: 1
  scenarios:
    - name: "connect and send message"
    engine: "socketio"
    flow:
      - emit:
        channel: "message"
        data: "Blah Blah Blah"
```

this is what printed in console by server:

```
new socket connected: /#XC9WsjSeGw9hD7jZAAAA
new socket connected: /#NkVDJjHIO6DePiwNAAAB
socket /#NkVDJjHIO6DePiwNAAAB send message
disconnect: /#XC9WsjSeGw9hD7jZAAAA
disconnect: /#NkVDJjHIO6DePiwNAAAB
```

as you can see, there is one socket more, there is always connect one more socket per simulated user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It Was a bug in version of artillery, Fixed in 1.6.0-5

[issue link](https://github.com/shoreditch-ops/artillery/issues/233)